# Displaying certain part from external site on my site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have to work on website which is in wordpress. Here I have to display a part of website https://weather.com/maps/currentussnowcover. "Current Snowcover" section from this site,including the map display there. And that map will be update according to weather. I am newbie and I don't know how can I do this. Any help?

Comment: Check this out https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/?MR=1

Comment: I got there from here https://weather.com/xoap

Comment: how can it help me?

Comment: It looks like they provide an API

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

- Use Iframe and show the website page in that Iframe
- If they provide WEB API, then integrate it in your code, by getting the response and show it and update it regularly.

Comment: I don't have API, and I don't know how to work with it. how can I do it using IFrame?